# Android OpenGL ES - Can't bind more than 9 textures on some devices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

First off, sorry for my bad English.

I'm making 2D scene for my Application. There are 13 textures in my scene, so I bound these textures by following code. (I hardcoded it cause I'm testing it)

```
    //Prepare texture bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.scene02_bg, bfo);
            //Bind Texture
            int[] texturenames = new int[13];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(13, texturenames, 0);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            //Load Texture
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

            //Recycle bitmap
            bmp.recycle();

    //for second texture
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.scene02_campfire, bfo);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[1]);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
            bmp.recycle();

    //............
    //............
    //............

     bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.scene02_tree09, bfo);
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE12);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[12]);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
            bmp.recycle();
```

And then, I tested it on three devices, Samsung Galaxy S3, Note 4, and S5.

Note 4 and S5 renders properly, all 13 of them. But Galaxy S3 renders only 9 textures, after 10th texture, it renders texturenames[0]'s texture.

Since Note 4 and S5 runs perfectly, I thought my code has no problem. I googled it for hours, but I can't even figure what is problem with this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

-
for more detail, I attach my shader and rendering code.

```
    public static final String VERTEXSHADER_TEXTURE =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
                    "}";

    public static final String FRAGMENTSHADER_TEXTURE =
                    "precision mediump float;" +
                    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
                    "}";


   public void Draw(float[] mvpMatrix){
        int mPositionHandle, mMVPMatrixHandle;

        float[] mvp;
        mvp = mvpMatrix.clone();

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0, mScale, mScale, 1);

        Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mPositionX, mPositionY, mPositionZ);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1f);

        mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

        mTempMatrix = mvp.clone();
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mTextureShaderProgram);

        /*Setup vertex*/
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mTextureShaderProgram, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        /*Setup camera view*/
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mTextureShaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvp, 0);

        //Setup Texture
        int texCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mTextureShaderProgram, "a_texCoord");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer);
        int samplerHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mTextureShaderProgram, "s_texture");
        GLES20.glUniform1i(samplerHandle, textureIndex);

        /*Draw*/
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your rendering-code, I assume that you bound each texture to its own texture unit:

Most probably you exceed the allowed number of textures that can be used at the same time. In OpenGL ES smaller or equal 2.0 it is only guaranteed that 8 texture units can be used at the same time although there can be more. You can query the limit using `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, ...);`.

What you can do in your application (and since you are only using one texture at a time), is to rebind every texture to, e.g., TEXTURE_UNIT0 instead of assigning each texture to its own unit. The drawing code will then look like this:

```
int samplerHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mTextureShaderProgram, "s_texture");
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[textureIndex]);
GLES20.glUniform1i(samplerHandle, 0);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
                      GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
```